# getting an error on javascript. creating a word game

Tags: javascript

```
var feedback = prompt("rate the game 1-10");

if (feedback < 8) {
  console.log("This is just the beginning of my game empire. Stay tuned for more!");
} else (feedback > 8) {
  console.log("I slaved away at this game and you gave me that score?! The nerve! Just you wait!");
}
```

Comment: Well, what’s the error? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: This is pretty trivial but usually one should post a traceback or some more info :P

Comment: Same as all the answers below : you forgot that it should be `else if (feedback > 8)`

Comment: Sorry for not being too detailed. I'm new to the community. I apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

else should not have a condition after it :)
Also your comparison seems backward ;)
10 I think is usually a high score!

Comment: Sorry for not being too detailed. When it runs, it should prompt the user to rate the game from 1-10. If the User rates 8 or above, it will  say This is just the beginning of my game empire. Stay tuned for more!". If the user rates it 8 or below, then it will say "I slaved away at this game and you gave me that score?! The nerve! Just you wait!".

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it! Hopefully I will learn from this mistake lol

Answer (score 2):

It should be `else if(feedback > 8)`!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test another condition in an if-then-else block, you need another if.

```
if (feedback < 8) {
  console.log("This is just the beginning of my game empire. Stay tuned for more!");
} else {
  if (feedback > 8) {
    console.log("I slaved away at this game and you gave me that score?! The nerve! Just you wait!");
  } else {
    // What about feedback == 8?
  }
}
```

Comment: Or use `} else if (feedback >= 8) {`

Comment: Combine them into an `else if` - `if(condition) {...} else if(condition) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put another if or delete de second condition. Also it would be nice to check the insert value.

This

```
if (feedback < 8) {/* Stuff */}
else {/* other stuff */}
```

Or

```
if (feedback < 8) {/* Stuff */}
else if (feedback > 8) {/* other stuff */}
```

Also you should check the input value

```
function feedback () {
    checkFeedback(prompt('rate the game 1-10'))
}

function checkFeedback (fdb) {
    parsed = parseInt(fdb);

    if (typeof(parsed) != 'number' || parsed < 1 || parsed > 10) {
        alert('Number between 1 and 10 needed');
        feedback();
    }

    else logMessage(parsed);
}

function logMessage(feedback) {
    if (feedback<8)
        console.log('This is just the beginning of my game empire. Stay tuned for more!')
    else
        console.log('I slaved away at this game and you gave me that score?! The nerve! Just you wait!')
}

feedback();
```